# NSFetchedResultsController with pull-to-refresh shows nothing after update

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, refresh, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**The problem:**

When I do a total Core Data refresh via a pull-to-refresh control (deleting everything and then adding everything again), my automatic NSFetchedResultsController (CoreDataTableViewController) just deletes all rows and doesn't show the new data.

**My setup:**

I use a Core Data datastore which I fetch data from via the use of a subclass of [CoreDataTableVewController](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall). In this case, I have a list of groups the logged-in user is added to, which is fetched by using the predicate:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users CONTAINS %@", self.currentUser];`

I then use a datastore refresh function (the same as on app startup) to refresh the data, via a pull-to-refresh control ([SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh)).

```
[self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
        DatabaseMerger *merger = [DatabaseMerger sharedInstance];
        [merger refreshDatabase:self.context];
        self.tableView.pullToRefreshView.lastUpdatedDate = [NSDate date];
    }];
```

In this refresh, all the Core Data Managed Objects get deleted, and then added again with the use of JSON data.

With the use of the CoreDataTableViewController, which observes the context, the rows should be refreshed if the context changes. Currently, the only thing that changes, is that all the rows disappear.

The weird thing is, that when I pop the viewcontroller, and push it again (via the navigationbar's back-button), the rows are correctly displayed with the data. This seems to me that it is a problem with fetching the data realtime.

**What I have tried:**

- Manually refetching the data via the use of `[self.fetchedresultscontroller performFetch:&error]`
- Deleting the fetchedresultscontroller's cache via the use of `[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil]`
- Setting the fetchresultscontroller to nil, and then setting the controller up again

**Relevant Code:**

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{    
    NSFetchRequest *groupRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Group"];
    groupRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
    groupRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users CONTAINS %@", self.currentUser];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:groupRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.debug = YES;
    self.currentUser = [Settings currentUser:self.context];
    [self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
        DatabaseMerger *merger = [DatabaseMerger sharedInstance];
        [merger refreshDatabase:self.context];
        self.tableView.pullToRefreshView.lastUpdatedDate = [NSDate date];
    }];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveFinishedNotification:)
                                                 name:@"dataMergeFinished"
                                               object:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)receiveFinishedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"dataMergeFinished"]) {
        [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];

        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error) {
            DebugLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}
```

**I am using iOS 5.1.1 with ARC**

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the NSFetchedResultsController delegates? If you haven't the FRC wont auto-update.

implement the following:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"POSTDETAIL: controllerWillChangeContent");
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"POSTDETAIL: controllerDidChangeContent");

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

That should refresh your table view

Comment: Yeah. I am using the CoreDataTableViewController subclass. This is a subclass of UITableViewController which implements all of the NSFetchedResultsController's methods and delegates, and allows for auto-updates when the context changes. So I think either the context is wrong after updating (unlikely because reopening the viewcontroller gives correct data), or there is something wrong with my implementation of the class.

Comment: Well I do pretty much the exact same thing in my class, but after you do the merge I *have* to call [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error] and then [self.tableView reloadData]; I dont subclass UITableViewController - but the reloadData was important to get the tableview to show updated data (specifically as my initial fetch may return 0 results, and then I do a web-api call/merge then performFetch)